# Link Domain to home server

Tags: dns, ip, domain

I've bought a domain (for i.e. www.mydomain.co.uk) and I've a home web server with nginx and PHP5. I want link the domain with my static home IP. What should I do?

What I did: I tried to put in name server my static IP, but it's not possible, why is this not allowed?

I read I have to install a DNS, why?

Comment: The direct (perhaps incomplete) answer to "why is this not allowed?" is that the `NS` records for your domain must be registered nameservers, meaning the `nsX.nic.uk` servers must be aware of them so that recursion works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DNS server how systems on the Internet (a web browser running on a computer connected to the internet, a server running a website, etc) figures out how to find what to talk to when it asks for a domain name.

In other words, its the 'Name' to IP address translation - without it nothing would be able to figure out that when going to mydomain.co.uk that it needs to talk to your PHP server.

The company/website that you bought your domain from probably has a DNS server you can use for free, and there are many other DNS systems out there you can pay for if you want to. A quick google search on DNS providers should get you going in that regard.

You cannot put just any old IP address in a DNS configuration, as if the system running on that IP address does not have a DNS server running on it, it just won't work.  You can actually put something in, but its pretty much a total waste of time  ;)

I recommend going and having a look at your domain name providers website and seeing if they have a DNS offering, or using google and looking for one of the paid for services is that is more to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you would like to make public use of the new domain.  Generally this is the purpose of securing a domain.  If you just want it for your internal use, you can use it without permission and as long as the public never "sees" your DNS server and you never need to access the "true" domain, everything is fine.

OK.  To use your domain in the public, you need to publicize it, the easy way is to find a hosting company that will give you an "all in one" solution.  DNS, Email, Web (and sometimes more).  After all, having published the name, you want to be able to receive/forward emails and host a vanity webpage.  If you want to do it the hard way, you need to configure a DNS server the public can get to.  It MUST have a static IP, because of the next step.  After you have a fully configured DNS server with static IP, then you apply to the ICAAN to register your DNS server.  Once you have your DNS server registered (btw, you should have two), then you go to your registrar and modify your domain settings to point to your new DNS server.  Now  when the public tries to reference your domain, their station contacts the "hint" servers which points to your DNS server, which tells them your IP.  This is really a lot of work, and not recommended.

Beware, some registrars will offer to do hosting/email for a fee, which is often more costly than you can find elsewhere.  Some/most hosting companies will do the registrations often included in the hosting charge.  Dunno if I can plug...  dreamhost.com offers one free registration with full unlimited domain hosting for under ten bucks/mo, and you get web/email/a linux shell account and lots more.  I don't think they do .uk tho...  So pick another domain and have two!  No extra charge.